# Capture optional second group of digits (non-repeating) using regex

Tags: regex

I have a huge dataset, where I am trying to extract a group of 4 digits. The problem is, sometimes there will be a preceding group of 4 digits that I *don't* want. These 2 groups will never be the same as each other.

Example:

```
String String 7777 Some more string  
String 1234 7777 Some more string
```

In both cases, I want to extract ONLY `7777` (or whatever digit combination replaces it). There is no pattern to distinguish which number group will be in which position - any number from 0000 to 9999 can be in either first or second position.

If this were possible, I think it'd do what I want?

```
\b\d{4}{0,1}\s{0,1}(\d{4})\b
```

Optional 4 digits, optional space, capture 4 digits. But I've tried it, and some variations of it, but I can't get it to work!

A look-ahead seems like a possible candidate, but I don't understand how to construct the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead to check if there is no *subsequent* 4-digit number after it:

```
\b\d{4}\b(?!\s?\d{4}\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT0vS9/1)

**EDIT:**

To capture 4-digit number that is not followed by any text and another 4-digit number, you should use:

```
\b\d{4}\b(?!.+\b\d{4}\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT0vS9/5)

Comment: This one does work most of the time, but it fails in a few rare cases. I don't know what causes it to fail, but if the element is something like "String 1234 string. 123 string 7777", it matches both 1234 and 7777.
w0lf's pattern was not susceptible to this.

Comment: That was my biggest problem, yes. But every 1 in 6000 elements, I have a deviant. I didn't think to include it in the original question, because (1) I thought it might be outside the scope of regex capability and (2) I was more than happy to get "only" 99.9% of the work done! Gave you an arrow though, since you answered what I actually asked.

Comment: Please check: my answer is using word boundaries around the numbers so that we only check for *exactly* 4-digit groups after the one being tested. w0lf's answer does not cover that, his regex will also capture more than 4 digit groups. E.g. in `String String 77777777 Some more string`, all 7s will get matched. I do not insist. Just in case you get unwelcome results, feel free to come back here :)

Comment: His does seem to match the 4 first digits of an arbitrarily large group, where yours doesn't.
I haven't encountered groups larger than 4, but it never hurts to be safe. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression that matches the four digit group not followed by any other four digit groups:

```
\d{4}(?!.+\d{4}.+)
```

Online test [here](https://regex101.com/r/lM6xN4/1#javascript).